# Finger Tracking and Gesture Recognizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

So I'm developing an app where I have all my gestures are being recognized. My problem comes when I attempt to add `UIImageViews` wherever the finger touches the screen.

These Views are to follow the finger, which they do, but the problem is I believe they are swallowing the touches not allowing the Gestures to be recognized. I have tried:

```
[_fingerHolder1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[_fingerHolder2 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything.
I am adding these the View in the `ccTouchesBegan/Moved/Ended` methods, whereas the gestures are being recognized in their respective handlers.

I have looked at using the `UIPanGesture` but I'm having some trouble recognizing the swipes as well as setting the coordinates for the`UIImageViews` of the finger trackers while doing this.  Should I experiment with this more or is there a different solution?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If they are being "swallowed", how can they follow the finger?  It seems like those are mutually exclusive...

Comment: My understanding of the touches being swallowed is that the View is not letting the touches through the lower views....
They're following the finger because on ccTouchesMoved I update to move the ImageViews. Not sure what's confusing about it? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIImageView will receive and process touches, hence they will not be forwarded to the cocos2d OpenGL view (also a UIView).

To make this work you need to create a subclass of UIImageView and override each touches… method and manually forward the event to cocos2d's view, here's the example for touchesBegan:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].view touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Use this UIImageView subclass in place of the original ones you use currently.

That will make regular cocos2d touch events work, and it should also make UIGestureRecognizers behave as expected if you've added those to cocos2d's view.

Comment: So I attempted to do this but am not seeing the touches being put through.

I subclassed UIImageView and have override all the touch methods. But am not seeing my NSLog statement being output when ccTouchBegan is activated.

The finger UIImageViews appear and move slightly, and the gesture is recognized, but I'm not sure if it's the Views swallowing the touch or if my calculation for the View move is wrong. 
My view move is:
UITouch *touch1 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint pt = [touch1 locationInView:_gameBoard];
_fingerHolder1.center = pt;

in ccTouchesMoved.

Comment: does the uiimageview subclass receive touch events? If not check the userinteraction property

Comment: No it's not receiving the touch events. I have the userInteraction property set to YES on each of the SubClassed views (LGImageView).

I am recognizing the gestures on gameboard and it is set to userInteraction:YES, exclusiveTouch:YES, and MultiTouch:YES;
I have tried with all of those on and off, but still same problem.

Comment: Also, when I make a direct call to it from the ccTouchesBegan to the LGImageView touchesBegan its resulting in a loop of touches- So I feel like it's working, but it's not registering when I don't directly call it for some reason? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need (please correct me if I'm wrong), you want to move some UIViews when a drag(pan) event is detected, but you also add UIImageViews when the user touches the screen and this disables the touches.

You should set `UIIMageView.userInteractionEnable = YES`(by default is set to NO), basically every view that should detect touches should have `userInteractionEnable = YES`.

If you want to ignore some touches on some subviews you should implement: 
    `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` method of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

For handling different types of gesture you should implement the method:
    `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
    }`